# low level datastore entity to ndb.model.Model?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

mapreduce.input_readers.DatastoreEntityInputReader yields low level datastore entities for a kind. Can that low level datastore entity be converted into an ndb.model.Model based entity?

Comment: Just a quick-n-dirty thought: [grab the pb](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/datastore.py#974) from the datastore entity and feed that into [_from_pb](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py#2469).  Hopefully Guido will have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Robert says. Given a `google.appengine.datastore.Entity` instance `e`, you can convert it to a protocol buffer object with `pb = e._ToPb()`, and then you can convert that to an ndb entity using `ent = <modelclass>._from_pb(pb)`. You must know the right model class (and import it).